# How to report disruptive players?

Tags: zelda-tri-force-heroes

So I was in a game where one player did nothing but throw me and the third player off cliffs until the team had no lives.  I tried to find a menu or something that would let me report the player but found nothing.  Can I report team-killing players or avoid known trolls in any way?

Comment: @Frank It's pretty clear that the missing word is "throw."

Comment: @Powerlord You know what they say about assuming...

Comment: I've forgotten where the report feature is, but it should definitely be in one of the menus.

Comment: @Frank so I did... Edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the instructions in the game itself,  while you're in a game with them, touch their portrait on the touchscreen, then press A or B.

[image: Blacklist a hero]

Comment: Never talked to that lady. I tend to single player everything until I reach a challenge I'm too slow to solo.